# Themes with Eclipse & KDE?

Tags: linux, eclipse, kde, themes, color-profiles

[image: kde and eclipse]

I have been trying to use eclipse on KDE Neon and Eclipse opens up like this. I figured out that it's the "color scheme" that's causing the problem and changing it to a 'light' theme can make Eclipse look normal.
However, that would result in every application's theme changing.
Is there anything else that can be done?

Only changing the color schema of the text area will suffice

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by going to `Windows->Preference->General->Appearance` and selecting `dark theme`.

Comment: backslash, not sure why this answer is receiving a negative response, but apparently, people didn't notice that you are the OP, which changes the perspective a little.  That will be clearer if you accept your own answer (click the checkmark).  That will also indicate that the problem has been solved.